# $(this).find("a").attr("onclick"); onclick giving invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I m creating a dynamic tab using Jquery its working fine but giving error for anchor tag **onclick** error is **invalid character**.
See the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //when page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //hide all content
    $("ol.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();  //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); // show first tab content

    //on click event
    $("ol.tabs li").click(function(){
        $("ol.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); // add "active" class to selected tabs
        $(".tab_content").hide(); // hide all tab content
        //var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); // find href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("onclick"); // find href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); // fadeIn the active ID content
        alert(activeTab);
        return false;
    });

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">01</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">02</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">03</div>
</div>
<ol class="tabs">
    <li><a onclick="#tab1">Unique benefits</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="#tab2">Insurance</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="#tab3">Business Loan</a></li>
</ol>
```

If i use `var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");`

Its work fine.
Help out

Comment: why are you looking for the `onclick` attribute? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: your HTML seems invalid, you have an extra `</div>`. Besides, did you try [jquery ui tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?

Comment: If `.attr( "href" )` works fine, why not use that?

Answer (score 3):

Thats the expected behaviour.

Because, last time I checked, `onclick` was an event and not an attribute or property.
Also `href` and `onclick` are completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the content(function) of onclick this is how you can go about it:

```
$('p').click(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });

        $.each($("p").data("events"), function (i, event) {
            alert(i);
            $.each(event, function (j, h) {
                alert(h.handler);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick inline attribute is equivalent to this:

```
function() {
    #tab1
}
```

which is not valid javascript.  While href is a string value that tells the link where it should go when clicked (default behavior), onclick is a javascript function that is a handler for the click event to provide alternate behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the `onclick` of an element to an arbitrary string, this wont mean anything to javascript. Instead you should use fields such as the `href` or data-attributes to store information for use in events.

To use the `href` attribute, change your `ol` list to look like this:

```
<ol class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Unique benefits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Insurance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">Business Loan</a></li>
</ol>
```

And then instead of

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("onclick"); // find href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
$(activeTab).fadeIn(); // fadeIn the active ID content
```

And use this javascript:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
$(activeTab).fadeIn();
```

This will use the href attribute of your link to show the tab with that ID.

---

Alternatively, to use data-attributes you could set your list to be more like:

```
<ol class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" data-tabid="tab1">Unique benefits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-tabid="tab2">Insurance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-tabid="tab3">Business Loan</a></li>
</ol>
```

And use this javascript:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").data("tabid");
$("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
```

This approach uses [data-attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to hold the ID of the tab `<div>` you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick attribute is an event handler attribute is the same as what you are doing in this line of code on your script:

$("ol.tabs li").click(

See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onclick

In other words you are assigning the handling of the click event to a script by the name of '#tab1' 
The hash tag is an 'illegal' script char.

To accomplish what you want there are a few thinks you can do.
First use a data attribute.

```
<ol class="tabs">
        <li><a data-tab-name="#tab1">Unique benefits</a></li>
        <li><a data-tab-name="#tab2">Insurance</a></li>
        <li><a data-tab-name="#tab3">Business Loan</a></li>
</ol>
```

And them change your js line to:

```
var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("data-tab-name");
```

On a related note I will change a few more things on your script.
Since you are attaching the event handler to the onclick event of the list item I will add the attribute to the list item as follow.

```
<ol class="tabs">
        <li data-tab-name="#tab1"><a>Unique benefits</a></li>
        <li data-tab-name="#tab2"><a>Insurance</a></li>
        <li data-tab-name="#tab3"><a>Business Loan</a></li>
</ol>
```

That allows me to cahnge the js line to this:

```
var activeTab = $(this).attr("data-tab-name");
```

What should improve performance a bit but more important makes the code more readable.

Hope this helps.